# ASP Menu auto-adds clear div

Tags: css, asp.net, menu, css-float

I want my header to look like this:

```
Link | Link | Link                                               Image
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I have instead is:

```
Link | Link | Link                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------    
                                                                 Image
```

ASP code:

```
<div class="hideSkiplink">
     <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="true" Orientation="Horizontal" >
          <Items>
               <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" ImageUrl="~/ICONS/About/home_Icon.png"/>
               <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" ImageUrl="~/ICONS/About/about_Icon.png"/>
               <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/RestrictedPages/AdminMenu.aspx" ImageUrl="~/ICONS/About/admin_Icon.png"></asp:MenuItem>
          </Items>
     </asp:Menu>
     <div class="logo">
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ICONS/About/logo.png" />
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.hideSkiplink {
    background-color: #3a4f63;
    width: 100%;
}

div.logo {
   float: right;
}
```

Inspecting the element in `Firebug` shows:

```
<div class="hideSkiplink">
  <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink">
    <div id="NavigationMenu" style="float: left;">
      <div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

I think the div with `clear: left` is being created automatically and that is what is causing the issue.

What can be done to prevent this element from being created or is there a workaround to compensate for its inclusion?

Comment: will you please give me demo in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the exact same issue.  Its automatically inserting <div style="clear: left;"></div> forcing the next element down (exactly like your example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrange your divs properly

e.g.

```
<div id="dvParent">
    <div style="float:left">
        Link | Link | Link 
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        Image
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PhKhg/

Comment: This doesn't work.  The issue is that asp.net is inserting <div style="clear: left";></div>,

Answer (score 3):

The correct, and complete, answer is:

1) add, as "musium" commented, the following to your CSS

```
#IDOfYourMenuControl + div {
clear: none !important;
}
```

This will stop the unexpected

```
<div style="clear: left";></div>
```

2) add the following to your asp.menu tag

```
SkipLinkText=""
```

This will stop the unexpected

```
<a id="yourmenuID_SkipLink">
```

tag from being  created.

You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old… but I’ve just had the same problem and for me, the following solution worked:

```
#IDOfYourMenuControl + div {
    clear: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying how to figure out how to get rid of the div clear:left tag that was being autocreated, and this fit the bill.

Answer (score -1):

```
nav div:nth-child(a number){
    clear:none !important;
}
```